# opencv - sailfishOS IDE

Tags: c++, opencv, sailfish-os

I want to create an Sailfish app for Jolla with C++ and openCV. I worked with openCV and standard computers, but I have no experience with openCV and mobile devices. How do I have to integrate the openCV libraries into the sailfishOS IDE?

If I integrate the standard libraries like in x64 / x86 programs:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/opencv \
               /usr/include/opencv2 \
LIBS += -lopencv_core
```

and include them with:

```
#include <cv.h>
```

it is not posiible to use the opencv functions.

Has anybody experiences with openCV, the SailfishOS IDE and Jolla?

Comment: just out of curiosity: wouldn't you have to *build* the opencv libs for that os first ? i'd expect that part to be far more difficult than getting a demo to run...

Comment: I don't know. There is a openCV Version for Android maybe one can use it?
As I already sayed. I have no experience with mobile development. Want to start it with my new phone.

Comment: still, sounds like you're starting at the wrong end ? unless you get opencv working on that box,  - no need to worry about the ide ... no ?

Comment: Hm ok. Than I have to wait a bit until someone ports opencv to Jolla phones, because I am not familar with these steps.

Comment: Perhaps [this link](https://sailfishos.org/sailfish-silica/) would help you get a kickstart on things. There are links on that page for developing apps using 3rd party C++ libraries. Also, [this document](http://hardcodes.de/SailfishOS/Developing-with-SailfishOS.pdf) has all details about developing from different OS's.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV is already packaged for Mer: https://build.merproject.org/package/show/home:cckwes/opencv

You just need to build it for SailfishOS, install the -devel package under SDK and you're ready to go.